# Windows Closes my SFML project after running

Tags: c++, sfml

Everything is added correctly and I don't get any errors in the debug window. However when I go to RUN the application windows gives me the normal "SFMLProject.exe Not Responding" and then closes my application. I run a Tight computer and there is no virus protector doing anything to my application. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Here is the code I have but I don't think it will help. Just a simple "Music Stream"

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

int main()
{
  sf::Music music;
  if ( !music.openFromFile("music.ogg") )
    return -1; // error
  music.play();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sf::Music::play()` will only start to stream your music from the file (if it opened it successfully of course), and return directly. It is not a blocking function. This means that even if the music starts to play, your application will exit almost immediately after because of `return 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program shows *Not responding* because it returned a non-zero value. Somehow, SFML is not able to play the file. Check what the exact error is by reading the SFML documentation.

Where is your OGG file located? Is it in the Debug builds folder, or in the Release builds folder? Try providing the absolute path like `C:/Path/To/Your/File/music.ogg`